# crawling multiple webpages from a website

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
        for site in sites:
            title = site.select('a/text()').extract()
            link = site.select('a/@href').extract()
            desc = site.select('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

This is my code. I want plenty of URLs to scrape using loop. So how am I suposed to these? I did put multiple urls in there but I didn't get output from all of them. Some URLs stop responding. So how can I get the data for sure using this code?

Answer (score 1):

You code looks ok but are you sure that `start_urls` shouldn't start with `http://`

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
    "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
]
```

**UPD**

`start_urls` is a list of urls scrapy starts with. Usually it has one or two links. Rarely more.
This pages must have identical HTML structure because Scrapy spider process them the same way.

> See if i put 4-5 url's in start_urls it gives output ok for first 2-3
>   url's.

I don't believe this because scrapy doesn't care how many links is `start_urls` list.

> But it stops responding and also tell me how i can implement GUI for this.?

Scrapy has [debug shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) to test you code.

Comment: Hm looking at the simplicity of the answer I'm not quite sure I understood the question correct. I think your answer might be more suitable than mine but I leave it anyway since I think the OP might also be looking for the crawling process itself.

Comment: It means "Opriginal Poster" ;)

Comment: Sorry I mistype the code, it should start with "http://". The problem is that I want to scrape multiple URL's using this program. See if i put 4-5 url's in start_urls it gives output ok for first 2-3 url's. But it stops responding and also tell me how i can implement GUI for this.?

Answer (score 0):

You just posted the code from the [tutorial](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). What you should do is to actually *read* the whole documentation, especially the [basic concept](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/#basic-concepts) part. What you basically want is the [crawl spider](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) where you can define rules that the spider will follow and process with your given code.

To quote the docs with the example:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = Item()
        item['id'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
        item['name'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried to define the rules but that is not my actual problem. My problem is how to get the output of all the pages which i supply to start_urls? I am getting output in my .csv file  only from first 3-4 pages. I have near about 20 pages to scrape. So how am I supposed do this? After scraping these 3-4 pages my program stops receiving reply from the server.